# How to add the parcelable implementation for ArrayList of Custom object?

Tags: kotlin, arraylist, parcelable, parcel

I have created a class with an ArrayList of Custom object and some other string variables. I used "Add parcelable implementation" for making this class parcelable.

[image]

In the auto-generated code I tried using readTypedList for the TODO part but then I get the error which I have shown below. Also the custom object Cart which I am using is also parcelable.

[image]

Here is the code mentioned in the above images.

```
class Orders (
   var id:String="",
   var user_id:String="",
   var products: ArrayList<Cart> =arrayListOf(),
   var addressId:String="",
   val image:String="",
   val title:String="",
   val subTotal:String="",
   val shippingCharge:String="",
   val total:String="",
  ) : Parcelable {
   constructor(parcel: Parcel) : this(
       parcel.readString().toString(),
       parcel.readString().toString(),
       TODO("products"),
       parcel.readString().toString(),
       parcel.readString().toString(),
       parcel.readString().toString(),
       parcel.readString().toString(),
       parcel.readString().toString(),
       parcel.readString().toString()
   ) {
   }

   override fun writeToParcel(parcel: Parcel, flags: Int) {
       parcel.writeString(id)
       parcel.writeString(user_id)
       parcel.writeString(addressId)
       parcel.writeString(image)
       parcel.writeString(title)
       parcel.writeString(subTotal)
       parcel.writeString(shippingCharge)
       parcel.writeString(total)
   }

   override fun describeContents(): Int {
       return 0
   }

companion object CREATOR : Parcelable.Creator<Orders> {
    override fun createFromParcel(parcel: Parcel): Orders {
        return Orders(parcel)
    }

    override fun newArray(size: Int): Array<Orders?> {
        return arrayOfNulls(size)
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: the `product` value does not exists before your `Orders` object is created. Also, please post code, not images.

Comment: But there must be some other way for making my class parcelable.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the `products` list because it doesn't exist yet when you haven't called the primary constructor yet. Instead, create a list to read into. Since `readTypedList` doesn't return anything, you can use `also`.

So for the `products` line use:

```
arrayListOf().also { parcel.readTypedList(it, Cart.CREATOR) },
```

Comment: 'it' is not recognised. It is saying unresolved reference. Also for the arrayListOf, it is saying "Not enough information to infer type variable T"

Comment: Then add the type `arrayListOf<Cart>()`